# What's $(1-B)^d(a_0+...+a_{d}t^d)$?

Tags: time-series, self-study, lags

If $B$ is the lag operator or backshift operator used in time series, what's $(1-B)^d(a_0+...+a_{d}t^d)$? We can think of the polynomial as a trend in a time series process.

More specifically, what's $Bt^d$? $t^d-1$ or $(t-1)^d$?

Comment: In what sense is "$a_0+\cdots+a_{d-1}t^d$" a time series?  It looks like a polynomial.  If so, this question makes no sense; if not, please explain your notation.

Comment: $Bt^d$ is $(t-1)^d$.  It seems like a sensible question to me: when you difference a polynomial in time $d$ times, what do you get?  But maybe you need to put the self-study tag on this?  It seems like an exercise.

Comment: Does $t$ denote the time? What values can $t$ take?

Comment: @whuber I've added some more info. My objective is to use the answer to this question to understand why we can add an arbitrary polynomial trend to an ARIMA process, and still get the same difference equation.

Comment: @Viktor time takes values only on integers for the purposes of this question.

Comment: Shouldn't your polynomial perhaps read $a_0 + a_1 t + \dots a_{d-1}t^{d-1}$ or $a_0 + a_1 t + \dots a_{d}t^{d}$?  In any case, applying the difference operator $(1-B)$ reduces the order of a polynomial in $t$ by one so you end up with just a constant.  As to your specific question, $B t^d = (t-1)^d$.

Comment: The first bit is just expansion via the binomial theorem and a Cauchy convolution. I think @JarleTufto has the right idea for your second bit, but I would like more detail to be sure.

Comment: @TheLaconic Do you know if there's a formula for $(1-B)^d (a_0+...+a_{d}t^d)$? I'm trying to do this, but it seems a bit too complicated...

Comment: Yes, it's $a_d d!$  Proof posted below.  You could guess at it by thinking of the differencing operator as almost like differentiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there are important differences between polynomials and time series, let's look at this abstractly.

### Concepts and Notation

Consider a set $S$, a vector space $V$, and the collection of all functions $V^S = \{a:S\to V\}$.  The two examples to keep in mind are both where $S=\mathbb Z$ is the set of integers and $V$ is either (a) $\mathbb R$ or (b) the (real-valued) random variables defined on a given probability space $(\Omega, \mathfrak F, \mathbb P)$ (which I will simply write as "$\Omega$" below).  In this situation, elements $a$ of $V^S$ are often called *sequences*, their values at integers $i$ are written $a_i$ instead of $a(i)$, and are expressed in the form $$a = (a_i)_{i\in\mathbb Z} = (\ldots,\ a_{-2},\ a_{-1},\ a_0,\ a_1,\ a_2,\ \ldots).$$

The "obvious" rules for scalar multiplication and vector addition, namely

$$(\lambda a)_i = \lambda (a_i)$$

and

$$(a+b)_i = a_i + b_i$$

(for any $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ and $a,b,\in V^S$) make $V^S$ into a vector space.

Further suppose there is an injective map $\sigma:S\to S$, a so-called "shift."  The one to have in mind is $\sigma:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ given by $\sigma(i)=i+1$.  This induces a map on from $V^{\sigma(S)}$ to $V^S$, which (for clarity) I will write $[\sigma]$, given by $$[\sigma](a)_i = a_{\sigma^{-1}(i)}.$$  Explicitly, for our example with $S=\mathbb Z$, because $\sigma^{-1}(i)=i-1$, the sequence

$$-2\to a_{-2}, -1\to a_{-1}, 0\to a_0, 1\to a_1,  2\to a_2,\ldots$$

is mapped to the sequence $$-2\to a_{-3}, -1\to a_{-2}, 0\to a_{-1}, 1\to a_0, 2\to a_1, \ldots.$$  If you were to tabulate your sequences, like thus,

$$a: \left(\array{\ldots & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & \ldots \\ \ldots & a_{-2} & a_{-1} & a_0 & a_1 & a_2 & \ldots }\right),$$

then applying this "backshift operator" $[\sigma]$ appears to reach back one step and pull the sequence one step to the right, assigning the immediately *preceding* value to the current index:

$$[\sigma](a): \left(\array{\ldots & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & \ldots \\ \ldots & a_{-3} & a_{-2} & a_{-1} & a_0 & a_1 & \ldots }\right).\tag{1}$$

When $i$ is a time index, this procedure "looks back" one step in time. A key point is that $[\sigma]$ is a *linear* vector space map $[\sigma]:V^{\sigma(S)}\to V^S$.  This gives us a large set of tools from linear algebra and functional analysis for studying $[\sigma]$.

### Applications

We may understand a polynomial

$$p = p_0 + p_1T + p_2 T^2 + \cdots + p_d T^d$$

(where "$T$" is merely an abstract symbol) as determining a function, also written $p$, from $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb R$ via

$$p_t = p_0 + p_1 t + p_2 t^2 + \cdots + p_d t^d$$

for all $t\in \mathbb{Z}$. (It is conventional to use "$t$" as an index in this context to remind us of the application where $t$ indexes regularly spaced *times*.) The "backshift operator" $B$ refers to the induced action of $\sigma$ on $V^S = \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$.  As such, definition $(1)$ yields

$$(B(p))_t = ([\sigma](p)_t) = p_{\sigma^{-1}(t)} = p_{t-1} = p(t-1) = p_0 + p_1(t-1) + \cdots + p_d(t-1)^d.$$

This answers your "more specific" question (and the rest is just a matter of algebra, working in the ring of linear operators).  But let's go just a little further, because now the abstractions begin to pay off: we can immediately see the connection with time series.

**As another application,** let $X=(X_t)$ be a time series: it's a sequence of random variables indexed by $\mathbb Z$.  Now

$$(B(X))_t = X_{t-1}$$

is seen as the [usual backshift operator for time series.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lag_operator).

**Uniting these applications** is the idea that by taking the expectations of the $X_t$ for each $t$ separately, we map the space of time series $\Omega^\mathbb Z$ to the space of real-valued sequences $\mathbb R^\mathbb Z$ *via*

$$E[(X)]_t = (E[X])_t.$$

Obviously this (linear) map commutes with the backshift operator: $$E \circ B = B \circ E.$$  There's nothing profound about this; I have simply stated that it doesn't matter whether you shift the sequences before or after taking expectations--that's the result I hope is obvious.  Note, though, the abuse of notation: the two instances of "$B$" in the preceding statement are linear operators on *different* spaces.  If there's any chance of confusion--or when you're working through these ideas for the first time--it helps to remind yourself of these distinctions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer whuber. By the way, in your 2nd to last equation, shouldn't be E[(X)_t] instead of E[(X)]_t?

Comment: Also, is there a formula for the general case $(1-B)^d (a_0+...+a_dt^d)$?  I' haven't been able to reach a formula. thanks.

Comment: This is the algebra I referred to. It comes down to two ideas with which I am sure you and all readers of this post are familiar: first, that $(1-B)^d$ is obtained by applying $1-B$ $d$ times to the polynomial (which can be done  either iteratively or by applying the Binomial Theorem) and second, that since $1-B$ is a *linear* operator, it is applied to a polynomial by applying it separately to each power of $t$, multiplying those results by the corresponding coefficients, and adding up the results.

Answer (score 2):

Use induction.  This might be more long-winded than it needs to be.  I'll take for granted the linearity of the differencing operator $(1-B)$.

First, we show that

$(1-B)^m t^n = 0$ if $m>n$ and $n \geq 0$

Obviously, if $n=0$, then $t^n=1$, and so $(1-B)1=0$, and any further differencing also gives zero: $(1-B)^m 1=(1-B)^{m-1} 0=0$.  That's the first bit.

Now assume that $(1-B)^m t^k=0$ if $m>k$ for $k=0 \ldots n-1$.  Then if $m>n$,

$(1-B)^m t^n = (1-B)^{m-1} \left( t^n - (t-1)^n \right) = (1-B)^{m-1} \left( t^n - (t^n + b_1 t^{n-1} + \ldots + b_n) \right)$

where the coefficients $b_i$ are given by the binomial theorem but we don't really care what they are exactly here.  Then

$(1-B)^m t^n = (1-B)^{m-1} \left( - b_1 t^{n-1} - \ldots - b_n) \right)$

But $m-1>n-1>n-2>\ldots$, and by assumption $(1-B)^m t^k=0$ if $m>k$ for $k=0 \ldots n-1$.  Therefore

$(1-B)^m t^n = 0$ if $m>n$.  That's the second bit.

Next, we show that

$(1-B)^n t^n = n!$ for $n>0$.

again by induction.

If $n=1$ then we have $(1-B) t = t - (t-1) = 1 = 1!$, so that's the first bit.

Now assume that $(1-B)^{n-1} t^{n-1} = (n-1)!$.  Then

$(1-B)^n t^n = (1-B)^{n-1} \left(t^n - (t-1)^n \right) = (1-B)^{n-1} \left(t^n - (t^n + n t^{n-1} + b_2 t^{n-2} + \ldots + b_n \right)$

where here we care about the first coefficient in the binomial expansion ($b_1=n$) but not the rest.

$(1-B)^n t^n = (1-B)^{n-1} \left(n t^{n-1} - b_2 t^{n-2} - \ldots + b_n \right)$

By the lemma that we proved at the start,

$(1-B)^n t^n = (1-B)^{n-1} \left(n t^{n-1} - b_2 t^{n-2} - \ldots + b_n \right) = (1-B)^{n-1} n t^{n-1}$

By the assumption used in the second bit of induction, then, we have

$(1-B)^n t^n = (1-B)^{n-1} n t^{n-1} = n (n-1)! = n!$

which completes that part of the proof.

What you're looking for then follows directly:

$(1−B)^d (a_0+\ldots+a_d t^d) = (1-B)^d a_d t^d$

by the first part, and

$(1−B)^d (a_0+\ldots+a_d t^d) = (1-B)^d a_d t^d = a_d d!$

by the second part.